# Why can't i retrieve EXIF properties from an image?

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, exif

I Have an image with some properties that i can see in the properties dialog in explorer:

[image: Screen shot of the image properties]

But when i try and retrieve them using the property info as listed on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534416(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
var propItem = image.GetPropertyItem(0x010F); // PropertyTagEquipMake = 0x010F
var equipmentMake = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propItem.Value);

propItem = image.GetPropertyItem(0x0110); // PropertyTagEquipModel = 0x0110
var equipmentModel = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(propItem.Value);
```

I usually get both values back, but for some files I get the make back but the search for model returns an `ArgumentException` Property cannot be found.

Iterating through the properties on the image like this:

```
foreach (var prop in image.PropertyItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t:\t{1}\t:\t{2}\t:\t{3}", prop.Id, prop.Len, prop.Type, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(prop.Value));
}
```

(Based on [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84474/reading-writing-and-photo-metadata/) article)

Reveals that indeed the model property is missing from my image.

What gives? Is the metadata stored in some other format that i should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the camera model in this files isn't stored as an exif but as an other tag like a xmp or specific camera tag. You can check this for example on http://regex.info/exif.cgi.

When this is the case, I can recommend the great ExifTool from Phil Harvey (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library. It supports lots of different types of metadata (Exif, IPTC, JFIF, XMP...) and several image and video formats.

Available on NuGet.

If you can share your image, I can help diagnose this issue further if you like.